# Unable to copy from local file system to hdfs

Tags: hdfs

I am trying to copy a text file on my Mac Desktop to hdfs, for that purpose I am using this code

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal Users/Vishnu/Desktop/deckofcards.txt  /user/gsaikiran/cards1
```

But it is throwing an Error

```
copyFromLocal: `deckofcards.txt': No such file or directory
```

It sure exists on the desktop

Comment: You are missing a leading `/`. If it actually exists,the path would be `/Users/Vishnu/Desktop/deckofcards.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

Your command is missing a slash `/` at the source file path. It should be:

`hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /Users/Vishnu/Desktop/deckofcards.txt  /user/gsaikiran/cards1`

more correctly/efficiently,

`hdfs dfs -put /Users/Vishnu/Desktop/deckofcards.txt  /user/gsaikiran/cards1`

Also, if you are dealing with HDFS specifically, better to use `hdfs dfs` syntax instead of `hadoop fs` [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142960/whats-the-difference-between-hadoop-fs-shell-commands-and-hdfs-dfs-shell-co)]. (It doesn't change the output in your case, but `hdfs dfs` command is designed for interacting with HDFS whereas `hadoop fs` is the deprecated one)