# What is difference between hadoop and hdfs command line tools?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I see that `hadoop` and `hdfs` command line tools can perform identical operations. For example I can run `example.jar` using

```
hadoop jar example.jar
```

And the same using

```
hdfs -jar example.jar
```

What is difference between these two command line tools?

Comment: Can downvoter explain how can I improve my question?

Comment: The HDFS CLI page doesn't explain the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the only difference in the commands is related to the file system.

`hadoop fs` is able to communicate with various file systems.

`hdfs dfs` is only for HDFS.

[what's the difference between "hadoop fs" shell commands and "hdfs dfs" shell commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142960/whats-the-difference-between-hadoop-fs-shell-commands-and-hdfs-dfs-shell-co)

---

The rest of the commands, such as jar, are basically aliases, and if you use HDFS as your file system, compared to S3, for example, there is mostly no difference, though it's been said that `hdfs` binary is deprecated

Comment: I also noticed that if I use pseudo distributed mode and run `hdfs -jar example.jar` it will actually be executed in standalone mode (basically it just run a jar without awaring of hadoop cluster)  but `hadoop jar example.jar` will be in pseudo distributed mode as expected.

Comment: You should be using `yarn jar` anyway as pointed out https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html#jar