# error while running any hadoop hdfs file system command

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am very new to hadoop. I am referring "hadoop for dummies" book.
I have setup a vm with following specs
hadoop version 2.0.6-alpha
bigtop
os centos

problem is while running any hdfs file system command I am getting following error
example command : hadoop hdfs dfs -ls
error : Could not find or load main class hdfs

Please advice

Regards,

Comment: This is not about programming, right? Go to ServerFault and ask there, please.

Comment: the first argument for the 'hadoop' command is considered by the java compiler as the main class for the hadoop command you want to run, and `hadoop dfs` doesn't exist. It's or `hadoop fs -ls` or `hdfs dfs -ls`

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
hadoop fs -ls
```

or

```
hdfs dfs -ls
```

what do they return?

fs and dfs are the same commands.
[Difference between `hadoop dfs` and `hadoop fs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384479/differnce-between-hadoop-dfs-and-hadoop-fs)

Remove either hadoop or hdfs and the command should run.